# Force Unity Dash and/or Smart Scopes through Tor Network?

Tags: ubuntu

When I enter keystrokes into Unity Dash with an original Ubuntu 14.04 setup, my understanding is that these are sent to local- as well as cloud-based "[Smart Scopes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SmartScopes1304Spec)" on Canonical servers.

How can I configure Unity Dash to send my keystrokes through the Tor Network?

I am happy to provide "usage data" to Canonical, but not my IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'transparent proxy' for this and route your whole OS through Tor, but keep in mind it will route everything else as well.

The Tor wiki has the technical details for doing this:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

To just route the dash is tricky, I'm not sure it can be done easily.
Maybe it can be done by routing specific requests and such and let the firewall pipe it through Tor, but I have not seen such a guide for Tor before.